# Pagination code required to fetch all links and perform action?

Tags: java, selenium, pagination

I need to write a selenium with java code where I need to perform all image font and size check but there is a pagination
where the default page set is 50 what if I need to perform font and size check in each page. I have attached my code but it will
check only first page.

Scenario:
1.On Parent page only 50 links are displayed I need to click on each record and perform font/size check in same page
I need to again click on next page and perform same font/size check after completing it should navigate to parent page and
again click on other records and vice versa  but again we have pagination on parent page as well.

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='primary-cell-text link']"));
System.out.println(list.size());

//Here Pagination code is required ???


ArrayList<String> hrefs = new ArrayList<String>(); //List for storing all href values 
for (WebElement var : list) {
    System.out.println(var.getText()); // fetch the text present between the anchor tags
    System.out.println(var.getAttribute("href"));
    hrefs.add(var.getAttribute("href")); 
    System.out.println("*************************************");
}

//Navigating to each link
int i=0;
for (String href : hrefs) {
    driver.navigate().to(href);
    System.out.println((++i)+": navigated to URL with href: "+href);
    Thread.sleep(3000); // To check if the navigation is done properly.
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");


    Thread.sleep(5000);

    //Here Pagination code is required ????



    //Below code is to perform action
    List<WebElement> block=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='High' or text()='Medium' or text()='Low']/preceding-sibling::div"));
    for(int b=0;b<block.size();b++) {
        System.out.println(block.get(b).getCssValue("height"));
        System.out.println(block.get(b).getCssValue("width"));
        String h=block.get(b).getCssValue("height");
        String w=block.get(b).getCssValue("width");

        if(h.equals("16px") && w.equals("16px")) {
            System.out.println("Height/Width is Matching ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("height/Width not matching");

        }   
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000);


    //High Color Check
    List<WebElement> high=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='High']/preceding-sibling::div"));
    for(int h=0;h<high.size();h++) {
        WebElement hvar=driver.findElement(By.xpath(("(//*[text()='High']/preceding-sibling::div)["+(h + 1)+"]")));
        String highColor=hvar.getCssValue("background-color");

        System.out.println(highColor);
        String hexHighcolor=Color.fromString(highColor).asHex();
        System.out.println(hexHighcolor);
        if(hexHighcolor.equals("#e11900")) {
            System.out.println(":  High color is matching i.e:#e11900");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(":  Low color is not matching :#e11900");

        }

    }
```

Comment: What html does the next page element have?

Comment: You need to wrap the two color checks in a loop and then click the next page element. If you can't click the next page element you exit or if you have a default number of pages etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add logic for going to the next page like in web pages, we can either scroll down further or click on `next page` to perform pagination.

So for all pages that you have got, you can call a separate function to check your `css` values onto them.